# Rails - Does mysql temporary table available between different http request

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, temp-tables

I have written a code to create temporary table on every http request. For the very first request table is created successfully however on the second request it gives me error as `Table 'xxx' already exists`. when i restarted my local machine server(thin web server) and hit the http request  then again temporary table is created without error.

Does this mean that temporary tables are shared between different http request and are destroyed automatically when machine or server is restarted??

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know temporary table exists until connection to the database is closed. In Rais you have a pool of connections to the database and different requests can use different connections.

So if you create temporary table in the first http request, second request can use the same connection and you can receive a SQL error when is trying to create it again, but in second request use another connection temporary table will not exist yet.

Comment: how to use another connection in second request?

Comment: You can't choose which connection to use. Any free connection will be taken from the pool.

Comment: also have one question. if i use two different database in rails app then will there be two pools of connection or single pool of connection??

Comment: @sanjay-salunkhe, out of the box there is only onу pool, right? But it seems you can have separate pool for every ActiveRecord model class, according to documentation (http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html#class-ActiveRecord::Base-label-Connection+to+multiple+databases+in+different+models). I haven't used multiple databases and haven't dived into AR internals but it seems it will work as you expect.